# Drupal CCK date field with just hours and minutes

Tags: drupal, date, content-management-system, cck

How can I create a date field in Drupal just with hours and minutes without years and months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to change the granularity when you create the cck field.

[image]

Jut select what you need from that Granularity options.

You can also just format the date by creating a new format:

Click on the date and time date format page and then create a new format that looks like this:
h:i
That's the time and date

[image]

Select that format for display.

You can go to the following site to see more Date format string options:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: if i juct select Hour an Minute i get this error : "Granularity must include a year."

Comment: OK I added some extra instructions for changing what is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This should also help, http://drupal.org/node/134144#comment-1982750

- how to add your own formats
- set time only or set any php date setting you want